# Accessing MySQL database through SSH tunnel

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-code, ssh, ssh-tunnel, tunnel

At the moment I can access a MySQL database by SSHing in terminal.
This prompts me for a passphrase for a key

```
ssh test-db01.somedomain.com

Enter passphrase for key '/Users/yourname/.ssh/path/to/key':
```

which I enter.

At this point I am in the remote host and can simply type

```
mysql

> SELECT * FROM users;
> ...
```

and mess around in the console.

This can be a bit cumbersome for me, and I want to connect up my SQL GUI (by tunnelling) so I can visualise all my records and stuff (I am using VSCode database tool), so it looks like this:

[image]

I have a bunch of config and keys corresponding to this host in my `~/.ssh` folder.

The host I enter is the same one when I SSH in terminal.

That is, `test-db01.somedomain.com`.

As you can see I get a `SSH error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND`.

Any ideas what I can try here?

Comment: That usually indicates either A) you typed the hostname in wrong, or B) the DNS settings on that machine aren't correct and it can't resolve that hostname.